# Put image in column

Tags: graphics, formatting

Is there a way to cover a column of a two column page with an image (all the page height, no caption)? This should leave the rest of the page as is - just move the text of the column a bit further down. I've tried `wrapfig` but it seems that it messes up both text columns - leaves some text in both of them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is a little bit unclear! If you want to have an image in a column completely filling up the page height, there's no text left anyway, i.e. not even shifted down. It's shifted to the other column, however.

Comment: That's fine - all the text should move the next available column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the `[p]` option for floats will work for a single column rather than needing an entire page.  The advantage of using a float is that text will flow past it.

I used tikz to do the overlay and to determine which column it is in.  This works because tikz saves the origin location in the aux file.  Don't forget to run it twice.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe} 

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{0pt}{\textheight}% fill column with strut
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\pgfextractx{\tempdima}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{center}}{\pgfpointorigin}}%
\ifdim\tempdima>0pt \relax
  \node[below left,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) 
    {\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr 0.5\paperwidth-0.5\columnsep},height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\else
  \node[below right,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) 
    {\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr 0.5\paperwidth-0.5\columnsep},height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: full page with frame]

Comment: closer - is there a way to cover the full width + choose which column to put it on?

Comment: @spokus: What width? The width of the column? That's exactly what is currently displayed. Or do you want to include the gap between the columns as well?

Comment: paperwidth - end of paper. Cover half the page/same thing you do with height

Comment: So latex decides where to put it?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

The image is a little bit distorted, to make it fill:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}  
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=\textheight]{beeduck}

\columnbreak
  \blindtext[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Close - thanks! Is there a way to use the image spread to the full pageheight rather than just the textheight?

Comment: @spokus: Well, yes, if really necessary. I'll try